# Word to Describe One Who Speaks Politely but with Conviction

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, adjectives, vocabulary, adverbs

Imagine you are at a debate on a controversial topic. One of the speakers presents her case straightforwardly and with conviction; there is no doubting her stance on the issue. At the same time, you are struck by how politely and tactfully she addresses this divisive topic. Is there a single word that might describe such a combination of traits?

Comment: These are two different qualities. It's kind of like asking for a single word for someone who is courageous and humble. Why must it be one word?

Comment: I think **Aplomb** might be the closest to what you are asking for. _'She debated the controversial issue with great aplomb.'_

Comment: @JoeDark Yes, 'aplomb' indicates that she did it with self confident assurance. It doesn't actually mean 'with conviction', nor does it directly imply 'tactfulness', but I am sure that to do both of those at the same time, one would need to demonstrate 'aplomb'.

Comment: @medica I think this combination of qualities is rare, but not mutually exclusive. Perhaps I could dial "conviction" back to "certainty" and "tactfully" back to "respectfully".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what psychologists call assertiveness. Here's how wiki starts [its entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assertiveness):

> Assertiveness is the quality of being self-assured and confident
>   without being aggressive. In the field of psychology and
>   psychotherapy, it is a learnable skill and mode of communication.

However, not all general-purpose dictionaries are up to date and seem to define assertiveness in an opposite way. Here's what The Free Dictionary says:

> Inclined to bold or confident assertion; aggressively self-assured.

Merriam-Webster is sort of treading a middle course:

> [D]isposed to or characterized by bold or confident statements and
>   behavior